# How to create an European Amazon S3 Bucket using Zend_Service_Amazon_S3

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

with Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 you can create an bucket with this code:

```
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($key, $secretKey);
$s3->createBucket('my-fantastic-bucket');
```

The second parameter of createBucket is 'location'. Which value is needed there to create the bucket in Europe (Ireland)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide the location name of the actual location.

Each location has a name so you just enter that.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTBucketPUT.html

```
Specifies the Region where the bucket will be created


Valid Values: EU | us-west-1 | ap-southeast-1 | ap-northeast-1 | empty string (for the US Classic Region)

Default: US Standard

Ancestor: CreateBucketConfiguration
```

So your code can be like this:

```
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($key, $secretKey);
$s3->createBucket('my-fantastic-bucket', 'us-west-1');
```